# Android Wakelock open

Tags: android, push-notification, android-wake-lock

I am working with zoom call integration in my android application, I  need to get call notification and show in app when incoming call received from Zoom. How to unlock the screen and show the app?

It means need to unlock device when notification received from the backend.